# Муниципальный с прописной?

Tags: орфография

Выступил М/муниципальный академический хор. Название — с прописной буквы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это начало официального названия, то с прописной, если нет - со строчной.

Коллектив стал преемником Муниципальной академической хоровой капеллы, руководителем которой была на протяжении 45 заслуженный деятель искусств РФ Евгения Сафронова.

3 сентября в 19.00 в ДШИ №1  состоится праздничный концерт Брянского муниципального  академического хора, посвященный Дню города.

Выступил муниципальный академический хор г.Костромы.